# Folder structure in different android devices

Tags: android, android-service, directory

In my project there is an option to download a set of files.To check the storage availability I used the below code

```
public static int getSDCardStatus() {
    String extState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    int status;

    if (extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        status = MOUNTED;
    } else if (extState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
        status = READ_ONLY;
    } else {
        status = UNMOUNTED;
    }
    return status;
}

private String getLoginFolders() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File file = null;
    int status = Constants.getSDCardStatus();
    if (status == Constants.MOUNTED) {
        File f = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "/SOTC_OFF/.nomedia");
        f.mkdirs();
        file = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "/SOTC_OFF/" + sotcPref.getString("domain", "") + "/"
                        + sotcPref.getString("user_id", ""));
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

While making download in LG Nexus 4 and Samsung Nexus 4 working fine. But in Micromax a114 canvas 2.2 and Nexus 5 not working fine.

For reference the service class which I am using for download

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.i("StatusDownloadservice", "Ondestroy");
}

private int OFFSET;
private int LIMIT;

String data;
private final String TAG = "DownloadService";
private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;

public static int COMPLETED = 100;
public static int FAILED = 101;
public static int LOW_SPACE = 102;
public static int NETWORK_PROBLEM = 103;
public static int ASSERT_EXISIT = 104;
public static int PARTIALLY_DOWNLOADED = 105;
public static int NO_FILE = 105;

private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private Notification notification;
ConnectivityManager connMgr;
ArrayList<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> showAssetList;
RemoteViews contentView;

private SharedPreferences sotcPref;
PendingIntent contentIntent;
int downloadCount = 1;

String url;
String showname;
String showdatecreated;
String showId;
Messenger messenger;
int noofFiles;

Thread handleIntentThread = null;
Thread downloadJoinThread = null;
public Handler notifyHandler = new Handler();
int assetCount = 0;

// To track the app event
MixpanelAPI mMixpanel;
private SharedPreferences myPrefs;

// private boolean isServiceRunning=false;
public DownloadService() {
    super("com.iw.sotc.show.offline.DownloadService");
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 5 " + "DownloadService()constructor");
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "DownloadService... Constructor");
    OFFSET = 0;
    LIMIT = 3;

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.i("StatusDownloadservice", "OnhandleIntent");
    // Initialize the Mixpanel library for tracking and push notifications.
    mMixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(this, Constants.MIXPANEL_API_TOKEN);
    myPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SOTCPref",
            MODE_PRIVATE);

    final Intent intentCpy = intent;

    // synchronized (intentCpy) {

    /*
     * new Thread(new Runnable() {
     * 
     * @Override public void run() {
     */

    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 6 " + "onHandleIntent");
    connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    sotcPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SOTCPref",
            MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent.........");
    Bundle extras = intentCpy.getExtras();
    url = extras.getString("url");
    showname = extras.getString("showname");
    showdatecreated = extras.getString("showdatecreated");

    // sara
    if (showdatecreated.contains("/")) {
        data = showdatecreated.replaceAll("/", "#");
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("date");
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    } else {
        data = showdatecreated;
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("date in else");
            System.out.println(showdatecreated);
            System.out.println(data);
        }

    }
    showId = extras.getString("share_id");
    noofFiles = extras.getInt("noofFiles");

    messenger = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");

    /*
     * Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(); contentIntent =
     * PendingIntent.getService( getApplicationContext(), 1,
     * notificationIntent, 0);
     */
    // contentIntent =
    // PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
    // notificationIntent, 0);
    showNotification();

    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.i("FOO", "Notification started");

    if (showname.length() > 18)
        showname = showname.substring(0, 17);

    if (DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT == 0) {
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 7 "
                    + "if(DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT == 0)");
            Log.i("Downloadassetvalue", ""
                    + DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        downloadSetofAssets(OFFSET, LIMIT, url);
        assetCount = DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT;
        if (Constants.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 7 asset count :" + assetCount);
        DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT = 0;
    }
    if (assetCount > LIMIT) {
        if (Constants.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 7.1 "
                    + "if(DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT > LIMIT)");
        for (OFFSET = LIMIT; OFFSET < assetCount;) {
            if (Constants.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Offline step 8.1 "
                                + "for(OFFSET = LIMIT; OFFSET < DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT;)");
            downloadSetofAssets(OFFSET, LIMIT, url);
            OFFSET = OFFSET + LIMIT;
        }
        DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT = 0;
    }

    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "download check :downloadJoinThread is running");
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.i("DownloadingStatus", "InService");
    if (downloadCount >= 1) {
        result = DownloadService.COMPLETED;
        // to notify the changes made after the offline
        // coded by Karthikeyan V
        showNotificationDownloadComplete("download successful.");


        Message msg = Message.obtain();

        try {
            if (Constants.DEBUG)
                Log.i("DownloadServicestatus", "Sendmessenger");
            msg.arg1 = result;
            messenger.send(msg);

        } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
            if (Constants.DEBUG)
                Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
        }

    } else {
        result = DownloadService.FAILED;
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.arg1 = result;
        try {
            messenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // stopForeground(true);
        /*
         * notification.setLatestEventInfo(DownloadService.this,
         * "Download Failed", "", contentIntent);
         */
        showNotificationDownloadComplete("download failed.");
    }

    /*
     * }
     * 
     * }).start();
     */
    /*
     * //to notify the changes made after the offline
     * ViewShowList.showListadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     */

    // }

}

private void showNotificationDownloadComplete(String statusDownload) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.sotc_notification_icon, "",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.upload_progress_aftercomplete);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    contentView
            .setImageViewResource(R.id.imageOfflineshowCompletion, R.drawable.icon);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1offlineshowCompletion, showname+"\t"+statusDownload);

    //For click event
    Intent intentOpenOfflineshows = new Intent(this,
            com.iw.sotc.show.offline.ViewOfflineShows.class);
    contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2,
            intentOpenOfflineshows, 0);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
            | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    notification.contentView = contentView;
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

private void showNotification() {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.sotc_notification_icon, "",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.upload_progress_bar);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    contentView
            .setImageViewResource(R.id.imageOfflineshow, R.drawable.icon);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, showname);
    contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100, 0, false);

    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
    notification.contentView = contentView;
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    /*
     * notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
     * .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); notification = new
     * Notification( R.drawable.sotc_notification_icon, "", System
     * .currentTimeMillis()); notification.flags = notification.flags |
     * Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; notification.flags|=
     * Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; notification.contentView = new
     * RemoteViews( getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
     * R.layout.upload_progress_bar); notification.icon =
     * R.drawable.sotc_notification_icon;
     * notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, showname);
     * notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
     * notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100, 0,
     * false); notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
     * startForeground(1, notification);
     */

}

private void downloadSetofAssets(int OFFSET, int LIMIT, String url) {

    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 8 " + "downloadSetofAssets");

    if (Constants.DEBUG)

        try {
            url = url.replace("value1",
                    URLEncoder.encode("" + OFFSET, "UTF-8"));
            url = url.replace("value2",
                    URLEncoder.encode("" + LIMIT, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.i(TAG, "Show offline -- Asset URL: " + url);
    showAssetList = DownloadAssets.hit(getApplicationContext(), url);

    for (ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> asset : showAssetList) {

        String thumbUrl = asset.get("thumb_url");

        // String normalUrl = asset.get("normal_url");
        // added by Karthikeyan v
        // To avoid downloading png file for document type files
        // here just used the variable name as normalUrl for testing purpose
        // // do not confuse
        String largeUrl = asset.get("large_url");

        String normalUrl = asset.get("normal_url");

        String mp4Url = asset.get("mp4_url");
        String fileType = asset.get("filetype");
        String assetID = asset.get("id");
        String assetType = asset.get("asset_type");

        if (Constants.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Thumb Url :" + thumbUrl);
        if (Constants.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Normal Url :" + normalUrl);
        if (Constants.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Asset ID : " + assetID);
        if (Constants.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Asset Type : " + assetType);
        if (Constants.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "MP4 Url : " + mp4Url);
        if (Constants.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "FileType : " + fileType);

        if (assetType.equals("1")) { // Image

            File assetDirectory = createAssetDirectory(showId, showname,
                    data, assetID, assetType);
            if (assetDirectory != null) {

                File thumb = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "/Thumb");

                thumb.mkdirs();

                // Thumbnail
                File thumbFile = new File(thumb.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "/Thumb." + getExtention(thumbUrl));
                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Thumb File ath : "
                                    + thumbFile.getAbsolutePath());
                doInBackground(this, thumbUrl,
                        thumbFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

                File normal = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "/Normal");
                normal.mkdirs();

                // Normal
                File normalFile = new File(normal.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "/Normal." + getExtention(normalUrl));
                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.i("NormalFilepath", normalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Normal File path: "
                                    + normalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                doInBackground(this, normalUrl,
                        normalFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);
                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.i("DownloadServicestatus", "DownloadComplete");

            }
        } else if (assetType.equals("2")) { // Video

            File assetDirectory = createAssetDirectory(showId, showname,
                    data, assetID, assetType);
            if (assetDirectory != null) {
                if (!fileType.equals("Youtube")) { // via AddLink
                    File thumb = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),
                            "/Thumb");
                    thumb.mkdirs();

                    // Thumbnail
                    File thumbFile = new File(thumb.getAbsolutePath(),
                            "/Thumb." + getExtention(thumbUrl));
                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "Thumb File ath : "
                                        + thumbFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    doInBackground(this, thumbUrl,
                            thumbFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

                    File mp4url = new File(
                            assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal");
                    mp4url.mkdirs();

                    // mp4_Url
                    File mp4File = new File(mp4url.getAbsolutePath(),
                            "/Normal." + getExtention(mp4Url));
                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "Normal File path: "
                                        + mp4File.getAbsolutePath());
                    doInBackground(this, mp4Url,
                            mp4File.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.i("DownloadServicestatus", "DownloadComplete");
                } else if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Asset type is video but is Youtube link. So not proceeding for offline");

            }
        } else if (assetType.equals("3")) { // Audio

            File assetDirectory = createAssetDirectory(showId, showname,
                    data, assetID, assetType);
            if (assetDirectory != null) {

                File thumb = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "/Thumb");
                thumb.mkdirs();

                // Thumbnail
                File thumbFile = new File(thumb.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "/Thumb." + getExtention(thumbUrl));
                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Thumb File ath : "
                                    + thumbFile.getAbsolutePath());
                doInBackground(this, thumbUrl,
                        thumbFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

                File normal = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "/Normal");
                normal.mkdirs();
                // Normal
                File normalFile = new File(normal.getAbsolutePath(),
                        "/Normal." + getExtention(normalUrl));
                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Normal File path: "
                                    + normalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                doInBackground(this, normalUrl,
                        normalFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.i("DownloadServicestatus", "DownloadComplete");

            }
        } else {

            if (!assetType.equals("5")) {
                File assetDirectory = createAssetDirectory(showId,
                        showname, data, assetID, assetType);
                if (assetDirectory != null) {
                    File thumb = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(),
                            "/Thumb");
                    thumb.mkdirs();

                    // Thumbnail
                    File thumbFile = new File(thumb.getAbsolutePath(),
                            "/Thumb." + getExtention(thumbUrl));
                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                "Thumb File ath : "
                                        + thumbFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    doInBackground(this, thumbUrl,
                            thumbFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

                    File normal = new File(
                            assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal");
                    normal.mkdirs();

                    // Normal
                    File normalFile = new File(normal.getAbsolutePath(),
                            "/Normal." + getExtention(largeUrl));
                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.i("Normal File path: ",
                                normalFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    doInBackground(this, largeUrl,
                            normalFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.i("DownloadServicestatus", "DownloadComplete");

                } else // "5" Link
                {
                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.d(TAG, "This is Web Link");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

private String getLoginFolders() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File file = null;
    int status = Constants.getSDCardStatus();
    if (status == Constants.MOUNTED) {
        File f = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "/SOTC_OFF/.nomedia");
        f.mkdirs();
        file = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "/SOTC_OFF/" + sotcPref.getString("domain", "") + "/"
                        + sotcPref.getString("user_id", ""));
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}

private File createAssetDirectory(String showid, String showname,
        String data, String assetID, String assetType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 10 " + "createAssetDirectory");
    File file = null;
    int status = Constants.getSDCardStatus();
    if (status == Constants.MOUNTED) {
        if (DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT != 0) {
            /**
             * From to concept here is to avoid duplication of new offline
             * shows when show is updated. So, we are here renaming previous
             * offline show's folder name with updated asset count.
             */

            boolean isRenameSuccess = false;
            File f = new File(getLoginFolders());
            if (!f.exists())
                f.mkdirs();
            File[] fileArray = f.listFiles();
            File f2 = new File(getLoginFolders(), "/" + showid.trim() + ","
                    + showname.trim() + "," + data);

            for (File from : fileArray) {
                String s1 = from.getName().substring(0,
                        from.getName().lastIndexOf(","));
                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.i(TAG, "s1: " + s1);
                if (f2.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(s1)) {
                    // Rename
                    File to = new File(getLoginFolders(), "/"
                            + showid.trim() + "," + showname.trim() + ","
                            + data + "," + noofFiles);
                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.i(TAG, "from existence: " + from.exists());

                    try {
                        isRenameSuccess = from.renameTo(to);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.i(TAG, "isRenameSuccess: " + isRenameSuccess);
                    break;
                }
            }

            file = new File(getLoginFolders(), "/" + showid.trim() + ","
                    + showname.trim() + "," + data + "," + noofFiles
                    + "/File_" + assetID + "," + assetType.trim());
        }

        if (file != null)
            if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();
    }

    return file;
}

public static String getExtention(String url) {
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    return extension;
}

boolean doInBackground(Context context, String urlPath,
        String destinationPath, Messenger messenger) {
    final String desti = destinationPath;
    final String url = urlPath;
    final Messenger messengerCopy = messenger;
    final Context cntxt = context;

    /*
     * new Thread(new Runnable() {
     * 
     * @Override public void run() {
     */

    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 9 " + "doInBackground");
    // boolean isDownloaded = false;
    int lastPercent = 0;

    File destination = new File(desti);
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.i("DestinationFile", destination.getAbsolutePath());
    if (!destination.exists()) {

        if (chkConnectionStatus()) {
            InputStream stream = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {

                URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                stream = conn.getInputStream();
                int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.i(TAG, "contentLength : " + contentLength);

                if (contentLength == 0) {
                    result = DownloadService.NO_FILE;
                    destination.delete();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            getResources().getString(R.string.Text_NoFile),
                            1000).show();
                } else if (contentLength > availablestorageOnExternalDir()) {
                    // No Space Available
                    result = DownloadService.LOW_SPACE;
                    destination.delete();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.Text_NoSpaceShow), 1000)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(destination.getPath());
                    long total = 0l;
                    final int buffer_size = 4 * 1024;
                    try {

                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
                        for (;;) {
                            int count = stream.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                            if (count == -1)
                                break;
                            fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
                            total += count;
                            int percent = (int) ((total * 100) / contentLength);
                            if (percent > lastPercent) {
                                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                                    Log.i("Percent", "" + percent);
                                contentView.setProgressBar(
                                        R.id.progressBar1, 100, percent,
                                        false);
                                notification.contentView = contentView;
                                lastPercent = percent;
                                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                                    Log.i("DownloadingPercent", ""
                                            + percent);
                            }
                        }
                        if (destination.length() < contentLength) {
                            result = DownloadService.PARTIALLY_DOWNLOADED;
                            destination.delete();
                        } else {

                            if (Constants.DEBUG)
                                Log.e(TAG,
                                        "Sucessful downloaded-------------------------------------------------"
                                                + downloadCount++);
                            // Sucessful finished

                            if (Constants.DEBUG)
                                Log.e(TAG,
                                        "Sucessful downloaded-------------------------------------------------"
                                                + downloadCount);
                            result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                    }

                    // To track the offline event
                    JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();
                    try {

                        properties.put("User Name",
                                myPrefs.getString("email_id", null));

                        properties.put("MAIL",
                                myPrefs.getString("email_id", null));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }

                    mMixpanel.identify(myPrefs.getString("email_id", null));
                    mMixpanel.getPeople().set(properties);

                    mMixpanel.track("mA_Show Offline End", properties);

                }
                conn.disconnect();

                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                msg.arg1 = result;
                msg.obj = destination.getAbsolutePath();
                try {
                    messengerCopy.send(msg);
                } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
                    if (Constants.DEBUG)
                        Log.w(getClass().getName(),
                                "Exception sending message", e1);
                }

                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.v(TAG, "Completed.............. ");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            finally {
                if (stream != null) {
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            // / no network connection
            result = DownloadService.NETWORK_PROBLEM;
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(cntxt,
                    "Please check your network connection", "",
                    contentIntent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.arg1 = result;
            msg.obj = destination.getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                messengerCopy.send(msg);

            } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
                if (Constants.DEBUG)
                    Log.w(getClass().getName(),
                            "Exception sending message", e1);
            }
        }

    } else {
        result = DownloadService.ASSERT_EXISIT;
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.arg1 = result;
        msg.obj = destination.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            messengerCopy.send(msg);
        } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
            if (Constants.DEBUG)
                Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
        }
    }

    /*
     * }
     * 
     * }).start();
     */

    return true;

}

public long availablestorageOnExternalDir() // Get Available space(in Bytes)
{
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath());
    long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize()
            * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
    long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.e("", "Available MB : " + megAvailable);
    if (Constants.DEBUG)
        Log.e("", "Available Bytes : " + bytesAvailable);
    return bytesAvailable;
}

public boolean chkConnectionStatus() {

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
        if (wifi.isConnected())
            return true;
        return false;
    } else if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
        if (mobile.isConnected())
            return true;
        return false;
    } else
        return false;

}
```

}

My queries :
1.Is anything need to check additionally?
2.Is the folder structure is different in many android devices?
3.If the android devices having different folder structure or storage options(internal or external) how can I look forward?

Comment: You could first explain why you want to download to a public download directory instead of the apps internal or external files dir. And yes the folder structure can be quite different among android devices. How to solve everything depends on the answer you give on my first question. By the way: `getLoginFolders()` will give a NullPointerException if the status is not MOUNTED.

Comment: @greenapps I just follow my senoior's code.

Comment: Well then ask him and tell me ;-).